# angular - vc-recaptcha in sibling controllers

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

I have a view where I have two sibling controllers - AppsController and CampaignsController. Each view contains a captcha widget respectively:

```
  <div class="sign-up-recaptca" vc-recaptcha key="'KEY'" on-create="onAppFormRecaptchaCreate(id)"></div>
  <div class="sign-up-recaptca" vc-recaptcha key="'KEY'" on-create="onCampaignFormReCaptchaCreate(id)"></div>
```

And in their controllers, respectively:

```
$scope.onAppFormRecaptchaCreate = function (id) {
    console.log('id apps catcha is ' + id);

    $scope.appsRecaptchaID = id;
}

$scope.onCampaignFormReCaptchaCreate = function (id) {
    console.log('id campaigns catcha is ' + id);

    $scope.campaignsRecaptchaID = id;
}
```

Both console.logs print undefined, however the Apps captcha works fine, maybe because it is loaded first. However, in the second one, when I run `vcRecaptchaService.getResponse($scope.campaignsRecaptchaID)` I get an empty string.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. In the html the `id` parameter must be replaced with `widgetId`.